# Generate citations or just list from a bib library that has the format [last name of the first author]˽(year)-˽ title

Tags: biblatex

So I have a bib library with over a 100 entries, I would like to change the citation style of the bibliography to the following format
[last name of the first author]˽(year)-˽ title.

Where ˽ is a space.

Alternatively, I am fine if I can somehow just generate a list with that format in at text file from my bib library.

The `.bib` file that has entries like this

```
@article{guo2010three,
  title={Three-dimensional thermal finite element modeling of lithium-ion battery in thermal abuse application},
  author={Guo, Guifang and Long, Bo and Cheng, Bo and Zhou, Shiqiong and Xu, Peng and Cao, Binggang},
  journal={Journal of Power Sources},
  volume={195},
  number={8},
  pages={2393--2398},
  year={2010},
  publisher={Elsevier}
}
```

And are cited in the article as

```
\cite{guo2010three}
```

I am using `biblatex`. My citations currently look like this

> [68]  G. Guo, B. Long, B. Cheng, S. Zhou, P. Xu, and B. Cao. “Three-dimensional thermal finiteelement modeling of lithium-ion battery in thermal abuse application”. In:Journal of PowerSources195.8 (2010), pp. 2393–2398 (cit. on p. 16).

But I would like to be

> [68]  Guo 2010 Three-dimensional thermal finiteelement modeling of lithium-ion battery in thermal abuse application

Or just have a text file output that has the entries in this format

The `.tex` file looks like this

```
\documentclass[]{report}


\setdate{\today}
%\setkeywords{LaTeX, Formatierung, EES-Vorlage}

\bibliography{LIST/literature} % Include literature

%%%----- Document ------------------------------------
\begin{document}

    %\listoftodos % Show list of todo's
    \maketitle % Show titlepage


    \tableofcontents % Show list of contents


    \begin{mainpart}

\chapter{Introduction}
,,,,

    \end{mainpart}

    \printbibliography 

    \listoffigures 

\end{document}
```

Comment: Do you really use `biblatex` as your tagging suggests? Can you show us an [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864) of what you have so far? (See also [MWEB](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/4407/35864)) Maybe you can even show us an mock-up of what you would like to see in citations and the bibliography.

Comment: Yeah I am using biblatex. My citations currently look like this
-----
[68]  G. Guo, B. Long, B. Cheng, S. Zhou, P. Xu, and B. Cao. “Three-dimensional thermal finiteelement modeling of lithium-ion battery in thermal abuse application”. In:Journal of PowerSources195.8 (2010), pp. 2393–2398 (cit. on p. 16).----

But I would like to be
------[68]  G. Guo 2010 Three-dimensional thermal finiteelement modeling of lithium-ion battery in thermal abuse application----

Comment: As for the MWE I have a bib library that has entries like this
---
@article{guo2010three,
  title={Three-dimensional thermal finite element modeling of lithium-ion battery in thermal abuse application},
  author={Guo, Guifang and Long, Bo and Cheng, Bo and Zhou, Shiqiong and Xu, Peng and Cao, Binggang},
  journal={Journal of Power Sources},
  volume={195},
  number={8},
  pages={2393--2398},
  year={2010},
  publisher={Elsevier}
}
----

And are cited in the article as --- \cite{guo2010three}

Comment: Can you please also show your `.tex` document setup? (This is what is meant with an MWE, please see the links.) Do you want the new format for citations or for the bibliography? (You write 'citation', but what you show us suggests you talk about the bibliography.)

Comment: Oh sorry, I am talking about the bibliography.  Check the out EDIT 2 for the tex file in the main post

Answer (score 1):

Since you want the same output for all entry types, you can define a new driver and remap all entry types to use that new driver.

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[style=numeric, labeldateparts, backend=biber, maxnames=1, minnames=1]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\DeclareFieldFormat*{labeldate}{\mkbibparens{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat*{title}{#1}

\DeclareBibliographyDriver{onlythree}{%
  \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
  \usebibmacro{begentry}%
  \printnames{labelname}%
  \setunit{\addspace}\newblock
  \printlabeldate
  \setunit{\addspace}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{title}%
  \setunit{\bibpagerefpunct}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{pageref}%
  \usebibmacro{finentry}}

\makeatletter
\def\do#1{\DeclareBibliographyAlias{#1}{onlythree}}
\abx@doentrytypes
\DeclareBibliographyAlias{*}{onlythree}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\cite{sigfridsson,worman,geer,vizedom:related}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]